# Stanley Kubrick's view on the structure of a film

Tags: stanley-kubrick

I have had the impression, for now quite some time, that I once read Stanley Kubrick said something along the following lines:

> A film is only made of five to seven critical moments, and that is what I choose to film.

The exact quote is probably very different to this, but the above captures the main idea: that Kubrick was not interested in a naturally-flowing, non-elliptical story but rather preferred to focus on defining moments. However, I have not been able to find any sources in the web backing up my impression.

**Is there any evidence Stanley Kubrick said something along these lines?**

Comment: Why is this question being downvoted and closure requested? The help centre specifically says "_the works of a director/actor/writer related to movies & TV_" are in scope and such a quote would obviously help in understanding Kubrick's directing style/vision.